# Passando parâmetros entre Views e Listando valores

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Saudações,

Tenho uma *View* **Index** que passa os valores da coluna "id" para outra *View* **Index**, conforme código abaixo:

```
            <a data-bind="attr: {href: url()}" target="_blank" href="@Url.Action("Index","Vw_RegistroVisita", new { id = item.id })">
                <i class="fas fa-street-view" title="Visitas"></i>
            </a>
```

O Código abaixo é a *View* 2 que recebe o valor da coluna "id" e faz a pesquisa:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
<p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            @Html.TextBox("id", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Digite o nome", style = "width: 260px" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
```

E esse é o Controller 2 da *View* que recebe os valores e faz a pesquisa:

```
// GET: Vw_RegistroVisita
    public ActionResult Index(Vw_RegistroVisita registroVisita, int id)
    {
        var estrangeiro = db.Vw_RegistroVisita.Find(id);
        ViewBag.id = new SelectList(db.Vw_RegistroVisita, "id", "nome", registroVisita.id);

        return View(db.Vw_RegistroVisita.ToList());
    }
```

Até aqui tudo certinho. O valor que eu seleciono na *View* **Index** nº1 aparece no TextBox na *View* **Index** nº2.

Agora meu pedido de ajuda: como faço para usar esse valor, que a **Index** n°1 passou para **Index** nº2, e fazer uma pesquisa e retornar os dados na **Index** nº2?

Imagens para ajudar
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sua pergunta está confusa... se você tem o valor do "id" na controller 2, basta pesquisar usando esse "id". Isso é o máximo que dá pra dizer, não sabemos de onde vem os dados, se é de um banco de dados (nem qual), se usa alguma classe ou framework (*ADO*, *Entity Framework*, etc), um serviço, etc, fica muito difícil dizer algo mais

Comment: Ops! Mil desculpas! Os dados vem de um banco Microsoft SQL e uso Entity Framework. Minha dificuldade é que não sei como usar o "id" para pesquisar. Sou novato em programação.

Comment: Só usar o método `Find` do *Entity Framework*. Imagina que sua entidade fosse "Cliente", o comando seria algo como `var cliente = db.Cliente.Find(id)`

Comment: Preciso mudar algo no código da View?

Comment: não vi sua view mas acho que não, você só quer exibir independe de quem seja certo? basta colocar o código na controller pra recuperar o objeto correto por id

Comment: Apareceu esse erro: "O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do tipo'mt2414_v6.Models.DataSet.Vw_RegistroVisita', mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[mt2414_v6.Models.DataSet.Vw_RegistroVisita]'."
Editei o post como ficou o Controller e a View

Comment: A view está esperando um objeto e não uma lista. Se recuperar um objeto por ID é de se esperar que só tenha um. Para testar tente mudar `db.Vw_RegistroVisita.ToList()` para `db.Vw_RegistroVisita.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Não funcionou. Retornou o mesmo erro. Se não puder "Id" pode ser também o "nome". Postei uma imagem para ajudar a explicar melhor.